# Discord.js How can I make the bot send a message whenever it gets invited to a server?

Tags: discord.js

I just want it to say some simple instructions or information in the chat whenever the bot joins a server.
Anyone know how I could do that?

Comment: You can use the guildCreate event: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate

Answer (score 0):

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    const channels = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "text");

    channels.first().send("Thank you for inviting me!").catch(e => console.log(e));
});
```